# How to count how many data point inside a region using 'segments'?

Tags: r, csv, plot

Is there a way to find out how many data points fall within a specified region on R? For example, this is my code:

```
data = read.csv("data.csv")
plot(data$X, data$Y, ylab = "Y", xlab = "X", pch = 1, col = unclass(data$classes), cex = 0.5, cex.axis = 0.5, main = "Y vs X Plot")
par(fig = c(0, 1, 0, 1), oma = c(0, 0, 0, 0), mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0), new = TRUE)
segments(-0.02, 0.36, 0.15, 0.36, col = c("purple"), lty = 1, lwd = 1)
segments(0.15, 0.35, 0.15, 0.9, col = c("purple"), lty = 1, lwd = 1)
```

Which gives me this plot:

[Plot of Y vs X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEfmU.png)

I want to know how many red circles fall within the rectangular region on the left (the one with the purple borders) or got placed on its boundary. Is there a way to do this on R?

Comment: `sum(data$X <= 0.15 & data$Y >= 0.36 & unclass(data$classes) == 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily using `segments()` itself, but here's a way of doing it with the numbers themselves.

I don't have your data, so here's some fake data:

```
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)
class <- sample(1:2, 100, replace=T)
plot(x,y, col=class)

# region we're interested in
xmin <- 0
xmax <- 1
ymin <- 0
ymax <- 1
rect(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)  
# rect was easier for what I wanted to show, but you can use numbers the same way
```

How many points are within the box?

```
sum(x>xmin & x<xmax & y>ymin & y<ymax & class==2)
# [1] 11
# your results will vary
```

How many points are on the border of the box?

```
sum(((x>xmin & x<xmax & y==ymin) | (x>xmin & x<xmax & y==ymax) | (y>ymin & y<ymax & x==xmin) | (y>ymin & y<ymax & x==xmax)) & class==2)
# [1] 0
# again, your results will vary
```

Comment: Thank you, this is an good approach too! Like @Axeman suggested, the symbols <= and >= can simplify the code a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to manipulate the columns from the existing dataframe.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
x <- runif(100, 0, 1)
y <- runif(100, 0, 1)
class <- round(runif(100, 0, 1))
df <- data.frame(cbind(x, y, class)) ## plot - insanity check 
ggplot(df, aes(x, y , color = as.character(class))) + geom_point()

## here x limits from 0 to 0.15 and y limits from 0 to 0.36

df <- df %>% mutate(div = ifelse(x < 0.15 & y < 0.36, 'Y', 'N'))
df %>% group_by(div, class) %>% summarise(cc =n()) %>% dcast(., div ~ class)
```