# How to find what objects get plotted in a region in R?

Tags: r, plot

I asked this question before: [How to count how many data point inside a region using 'segments'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44145731/how-to-count-how-many-data-point-inside-a-region-using-segments)

And received good replies. However, I have a continuation of this question:

How can I display the information of objects that got plotted into a specific region?

For example, my data.csv file is like so:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| name    | order    | x        | y              |
--------------------------------------------------
| file1   | A        | 0.234    | 0.124          |
--------------------------------------------------
| file2   | A        | 0.340    | 0.104          |
--------------------------------------------------
| file3   | B        | 0.057    | 0.368          |
--------------------------------------------------
```

After plotting the data like this:

```
data = read.csv("data.csv")
plot(data$X, data$Y, ylab = "Y", xlab = "X", pch = 1, col = unclass(data$classes), cex = 0.5, cex.axis = 0.5, main = "Y vs X Plot")
par(fig = c(0, 1, 0, 1), oma = c(0, 0, 0, 0), mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0), new = TRUE)
segments(-0.02, 0.36, 0.15, 0.36, col = c("purple"), lty = 1, lwd = 1)
segments(0.15, 0.35, 0.15, 0.9, col = c("purple"), lty = 1, lwd = 1)
```

And getting this plot, for example:

[image: Plot of Y vs X]

I want to know what are the name, x, and y values of the red dots just inside the region with the purple lines, not outside it.

On FORTRAN, I would do something like:

```
IF (order .eq. 'A' .AND. (x .GE. 0.23) .AND. (y .GE. 0.10) )           
    THEN
print*, name, order, x, y
```

But how would I do this on R?

**EDIT:**

**As was mentioned by Gregor in the comments, using the subset function seems to work like so:**

```
data = read.csv("data.csv")
plot(data$X, data$Y, ylab = "Y", xlab = "X", pch = 1, col = unclass(data$classes), cex = 0.5, cex.axis = 0.5, main = "Y vs X Plot")
par(fig = c(0, 1, 0, 1), oma = c(0, 0, 0, 0), mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0), new = TRUE)
segments(-0.02, 0.36, 0.15, 0.36, col = c("purple"), lty = 1, lwd = 1)
segments(0.15, 0.35, 0.15, 0.9, col = c("purple"), lty = 1, lwd = 1) 
testing1 = subset(data, x > 0.23 & y > 0.10 & order == 'A')
write.table(testing1, file="filename.txt", quote=F)
```

Comment: `subset(data, x > 0.23 & y > 0.10 & order == 'A')`

Comment: @Gregor Thank you. It seems to me the duplicate question is unfortunately not very helpful and isn't exactly what I was looking for, but your solution worked!

Comment: I mean, your question is essentially "how to subset data in R", I just picked a convenient dupe. There are hundreds of questions like this.